# Using FOR loops to put data into ref arrays

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I've tried to debug my program yet it isn't helping. I've only used WHILE loops to put data into arrays but I figured using a FOR loop here would be easier.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct record
{
    int item_id;
    string item_type;
    int item_price;
    int num_stock;
    string item_title;
    string item_author;
    int year_published;
};

void read_all_records(record records[]);
int num_inventory_of_type(record records[]);
const int max_array = 100;
int main()
{
    record records[max_array];
    read_all_records(records);

    cout << records[1].item_author;
    num_inventory_of_type(records);
    return 0;
}

void read_all_records(record records[])
{
    ifstream invfile;
    invfile.open("C:\\Users\\acsindle\\Dropbox\\Prog2\\Asg22\\Asg22\\inventory.dat"); 
    if (!invfile.is_open())
    {
        cout<<"file open failed";
        exit(1);
    }


    int slot = 0;
    for (int count = 0; count<max_array; count++)
    {
        invfile >> records[slot].item_id     >>
                       records[slot].item_type   >>
                       records[slot].item_price  >>
                       records[slot].num_stock   >>
                       records[slot].item_title  >>
                       records[slot].item_author >>
                       records[slot].year_published;
        slot++;
    }
    invfile.close();

}
int num_inventory_of_type(record records[])
{
    int slot = 0;
    int book = 0;
    int dvd = 0;
    int cd = 0;
    for (int count = 0; count>max_array; count++);
    {
        if (records[slot].item_type == "book")
            book++;
        if (records[slot].item_type == "dvd")
            dvd++;
        if (records[slot].item_type == "cd")
            cd++;
    }

    return book, dvd, cd;
}
```

My .dat file is as follows:

```
123456 book 69.99 16 Problem_Solving_With_C++ Walter_Savitch 2011
123457 cd 9.99 32 Sigh_No_More Mumford_and_Sons 2010
123458 dvd 17.99 15 Red_State Kevin_Smith 2011
123459 cd 9.99 16 The_Church_Of_Rock_And_Roll Foxy_Shazam 2012
123460 dvd 59.99 10 The_Walking_Dead_Season_1 Robert_Kirkman 2011
```

They're all separate on a single line with no spaces so there is no need to splice them. It should just be as easy as cin and stored. Not sure if it's my FOR loop that is messed up or if it's an issue with passing the array. Also my array is tied into my struct, is there a term for this? Is this what is considered a multidimensional array?

Comment: Did you mean `count < max_array`?

Comment: Could you please describe the actual problem? Whats wrong with the code you have? What is the expected result, and what do you get? Also, the first line is different from the rest, but you don't handle that differently?

Comment: Im simply trying to test the program by running the first function and then having it output just one thing. here it is cout << records[1].item_author; yet nothing comes out.

Comment: Also, why do you have one `count` variable and one `slot` variable? You could use `count` for both purposes. And you can not return multiple values from a function like you do in `num_inventory_of_type`, only the last (`cd`) will actually be returned.

Comment: I just plain removed slot and used count instead. I understand the issue with num_inventory, that isn't hard to fix. The for loop putting data in is the issue. Still not using it.

Answer (score 3):

The terminating condition is incorrect and there is a trailing semi-colon:

```
for (int count = 0; count>max_array; count++);
```

Change to:

```
for (int count = 0; count<max_array; count++)
```

Also `slot` is not incremented in the `for`, and only `cd` will be returned by the `num_inventory_of_type()` function: you can't return three values like that from a function.

A possible implementation:

```
void num_inventory_of_type(record records[], int& book, int& dvd, int& cd)
{
    for (int slot = 0; slot<max_array; slot++)
    {
        if (records[slot].item_type == "book")
            book++;
        if (records[slot].item_type == "dvd")
            dvd++;
        if (records[slot].item_type == "cd")
            cd++;
    }
}
```

You should check the state of `invfile` during read to ensure no failures.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to update my code. I took out the ; and changed the > to <

Comment: How is slot not incremented? I said slot++; inside the for loop

Comment: It isn't incremented, actually a different `for` loop.

Comment: @Nogg: Why not just loop on `slot`? I don't see that both `count` and `slot` are necessary.

Comment: For some reason it didn't put in right. The actual .dat file is 123456
book
69.99
16
Problem_Solving_With_C++
Walter_Savitch
2011

Answer (score 0):

Should have `count<max_array;` rather than `count>max_array;`

Answer (score 0):

Your for condition doesn't seem right, plus you got a semicolon that shouldn't be there at the end of the for

```
for (int count = 0; count>max_array; count++);
```

The test will return false at the first iteration

```
for (int count = 0; count<max_array; count++)
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot to update my code. I took out the ; and changed the > to <